# Next previous items in a collection

Tags: mysql

I am trying to work this out but not getting very far. If anyone could help would be great.

Basically I need to have previous and next items from all items in a table. If it is the last item  I need to loop to the first item. If it is the first item the the previous item needs to be the last item. Else the items need to increment and decrease by one. I need some way of adding this in one query so they are in the same order, or identified so in my app i can see which is the previous and which is the next button. This is MySQL so far but not correct. I am using 22083 as this is the last item in the table.

```
SELECT id, alias_title from image 
where ( 
         id = IFNULL((select min(id) from image where id > 22083), (select min(id) from image)) 
         or id = IFNULL((select max(id) from image where id < 22083),(select min(id) from image))
      )
```

Comment: Could you return the entire result set and then loop thru the results at the application level?

Answer (score 0):

Consider this example. 
For simplicity, it relies on the fact that `i` is indexed, but a more robust method could impose some proper ordering...

```
SELECT * FROM ints;
+---+
| i |
+---+
| 0 |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |
| 6 |
| 7 |
| 8 |
| 9 |
+---+

SELECT * FROM ints WHERE i >=5 UNION SELECT * FROM ints;
+---+
| i |
+---+
| 5 |
| 6 |
| 7 |
| 8 |
| 9 |
| 0 |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
+---+
```